# Why do my cluster_centers look like this?

Tags: python, k-means, data-mining

Why my cluster plot show centroid like this? even the separation of clustering data like this? and the centroid shows only in one point?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKisc.png)
And it shows strange coordinate of centroid

```
     [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
     [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 9.47966321e-04
  1.55790887e-03 0.00000000e+00]
     [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.65243990e-04 ... 0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 ...
     [1.28034216e-04 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
  5.54085687e-05 0.00000000e+00]
     [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 1.93483428e-04
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
     [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: There's no way to help without knowing about 10 missing key information points: Clustering method (tag says k-means), code for clustering, code for plotting, etc. 
Maybe you're accessing the wrong field in the clustering output? Maybe you're plotting the wrong parameter for the coloring and so the clustering is different from the visualization? Maybe you're showing only two dimensions while the separating dimension is mainly a combination of the 4th, 5th, and 19th dims? Etc etc etc

Comment: it looks like you have k clusters with centroids in n-dimensions, but your graph looks like a PCA/SVD/t-sne decomposition. There is no way to help here.